# Creating new table rows from query result sets

Tags: mysql, sql

Long time lurker, first time poster. I've been working on this project for a while and seem to be hitting a brick wall. I've looked through a plethora of postings regarding query equivalence but none see to apply. At this point I'm wondering if I can even do this in SQL or if I need to write a program to do the heavy lifting. So anyways, here it goes:

I have two labs Lab A and Lab B that both have compendiums (comprehensive test listing). I have tried to normalize the compendium to the best of my ability by creating an order code table for each lab, a results table for each lab, and a order to result table for each lab.

```
Lab A

LabA_Order_Codes

LabA_Order_Code       LabA_Order_Desc
000455                Thyroid Panel
000620                Thyroid Panel with TSH
...
999706                ECG Tracing/Computer Analysis

LabA_Order_Result_Code_Id    LabA_Order_Code    LabA_Result_Code
1                            000455             001149
2                            000455             001156
3                            000455             001164
4                            000620             004264
5                            000620             001149
6                            000620             001156
7                            000620             001164
...
19495                        999706             999706



LabA_Result_Codes

LabA_Result_Code      LabA_Result_Desc      LabA_Result_LOINC
001149                Thyroxine (T4)        3026-2
001156                T3 Uptake             3050-2
001164                Free Thyroxine Index  32215-6
...
004264                TSH                   11579-0
...
999706                ECG Interpretation    11524-6


Lab B

LabB_Order_Codes

LabB_Order_Code       LabB_Order_Desc
7020                  Thyroid Panel
7444                  Thyroid Panel with TSH
...
95594                 Retest Phenobarbital

LabB_Order_Result_Code_Id    LabB_Order_Code    LabB_Result_Code
...
10780                        7020               55075100
10781                        7020               55075200
10782                        7020               55075300
...
20579                        7444               55075100
20580                        7444               55075200
20581                        7444               55075300
20582                        7444               55075400
...
19495                        95594              99950100

LabB_Result_Codes

LabB_Result_Code      LabB_Result_Desc      LabB_Result_LOINC
55075100              Thyroxine (T4)        3026-2
55075200              T3 Uptake             3050-2
55075300              Free Thyroxine Index  32215-6
55075400              TSH                   11579-0
...
99950100              Phenobarbital         11524-6
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to populate a separate table that derives the order codes when the LOINC codes are the same (which would indicate the same test is being performed). If a LOINC "fingerprint" is unique, order codes for other labs in the row are null but common "fingerprints" all go on the same line. So when LOINC codes 3026-2, 3050-2, and 32215-6 appear together there should be an entry for both Lab A and Lab B in the same row with their respective order codes. Sorry for the long entry but I wanted to explain thoroughly!

In case it matters to anyone I am using MySQL 5.6.

```
Target Table

Test_Id     Test_Desc              LabA_Order_Code            LabB_Order_Code
1           Thyroid Panel          000455                     7020
2           Thyroid Panel w/TSH    000620                     7444
...
3490        ECG Interpretation     999706                     null
...
4210        Retest Phenobarbital   null                       95594
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a little tough to understand what you are looking for but I'll give it a shot.

It sounds like you should just split this up into a few passes.

I see your LOINC as a business key (unique on both sources).  So if you add LOINC to you target table you can do a insert/update process on each source.

**First Pass:** (update existing from LAB A)
   Get unique list of LOINC and Order_Code from LabA (Query)
**INNER JOIN** that to your existing target table (on loinc) and **UPDATE** Test_Desc, Order_Code for LabA.

**Second Pass:** (insert new from LAB A)
   Get unique list of LOINC and Order_Code from LabA (Query)
**LEFT JOIN** that to target table (on loinc) and **INSERT** new rows (with LabA null) **where TARGET.Test_id is null**

**Third Pass:** (update existing from LAB B)
   Get unique list of LOINC and Order_Code from LabB (Query)
**INNER JOIN** that to your existing target table (on loinc) and **UPDATE** Test_Desc, Order_Code for LabB.

**Fourth Pass:** (insert new from LAB A)
   Get unique list of LOINC and Order_Code from LabB (Query)
**LEFT JOIN** that to target table (on loinc) and **INSERT** new rows (with LabB null) **where TARGET.Test_id is null**

You should be able to put this entire process into one store procedure that you can call then and it will do it all for you.

If you are interested this is an **upsert** process if you want to read more about it.

Comment: Voglster, Thank you very much for your response. My only concern with your solution is that the LOINC codes cause the order codes to be repeated since there is a 1:* relationship between order codes and LOINC codes. That being said, if the target table you described acted as an intermediary and another pass was run to copy the table you described to the final target table minus the LOINC codes and id columns and looking for unique rows from the remaining columns. Does that sound correct? Again, thank you so much for your response.

Comment: I should also mention that multiple order codes can utilize the same LOINC code. I don't know if that would make a difference. (It is illustrated above by have two similar panels, difference being one has an additional result component and therefore LOINC code).

Comment: Yes a last pass grabbing distinct would work, however you second statement gives me pause, it sounds like a many to many and my solution would update multiple rows in this case and give you all possible LabA and LabB combinations is that what you are looking for?